# Bootstrap 5 hide col when device smaller than breakpoint size

Tags: mobile, responsive-design, grid, breakpoints, bootstrap-5

In the following example, the `navbar` is correctly hidden when resizing the browser window. However, it is **never** hidden (always visible) when using the "Toogle device toolbar" in Chromium.

The problem doesn't seem to come from the devtools of chromium though because once deployed, displaying it on a mobile (google chrome or samsung internet browser) still shows the navbar.

What am I missing here ?

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-md-start justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-2 d-none d-md-block" style="background-color: coral;">
          navbar
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8" style="background-color: aqua;">
          content
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not able to repro this behavior. It's hidden for me in Chrome devtools on smaller devices.

Comment: Yes, for some reason, it works when running in the code snippet. It's probably required to copy-paste in an html file and open it in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

...line.  Otherwise chrome will just scale (zoom) to fit.

See: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/#starter-template